# How to run different ENTRYPOINT commands in docker-compose.yml for different build environments?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-build

Right now I have a single `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3"

services:
  hello-world:
    image: hello-world
    build: .
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: development
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    entrypoint: npm run dev
    # entrypoint: npm start
    working_dir: /
    volumes:
      - ./distService:/distService
```

You see that I have 2 options for the `entrypoint` command. When I'm developing, I need it to run `npm run dev`. When I'm deploying it, I need it to run `npm start`.

How can I do this while keeping a single `docker-compose.yml` file?

Is there a way to pass some kind of build arguments / ENV variables to docker-compose? How do people usually handle this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, first up, you want to build your Dockerfile with the production defaults, such as ENTRYPOINT, baked in.

Then, its easy to take advantage of the fact the docker-compose will process both a `docker-compose.yml`, and a `docker-compose.override.yml` by default.

So, build your basic production ready definition in the `compose.yml`, and add the specific development overrides, such as local volumes mappings and entrypoints in the override file.

`docker compose up` etc commands will automatically work with your development stack, production deployments can be done by specifying `-f compose.yml` explicitly.

Here is an example of how this might be structured.

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM node AS builder

# Your usual setup here

WORKDIR /src

FROM builder AS build

COPY /src .
RUN npm build

FROM node AS final

COPY --from=build /src/build /app
WORKDIR /app
ENTRYPOINT ["npm", "start"]
```

#### compose.yml

```yaml
services:
  hello-world:
    image: hello-world:prod
    build: .
    ports:
    - 3000:3000
```

#### compose.override.yml

```yaml
services:
  hello-world:
    image: hello-world:dev
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: development
    entrypoint: npm run dev
    build:
      target: builder
    volumes:
    - ./src:/src
```